# c++ how to create a function wrapper?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I want to create a function wrapper that calls two functions `T1 func1()` and `T2 func2(T1)` that I pass in and returns type `T2`. Here is what I got so far:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct wrapper {
    wrapper(T1(*f1)(), T2(*f2)(T1)) : func1(f1), func2(f2) {}
    T2 operator() (void){
        T1 val = func1();
        // Here I want to do something with val
        return func2(val);
    }
    std::function<T1(void)> func1;
    std::function<T2(T1)> func2;
};

int f1() {return 42;}
double f2(int i) {return i/10.0;}

int main(){
    wrapper<int, double> wrapped{f1, f2};  // I want to skip the <int, double> here
    // wrapper wrapped{f1, f2};  // this only works for c++17 & later
    // wrapper<f1, f2> wrapped;  // is it possible to do this?
    std::cout<<wrapped();
    return 0;
}
```

It does work but has one issue: I need to provide template argument of <T1, T2> in the constructor which is a bit redundant (although I can skip them if using C++17).

I am wondering if it is possible to provide `func1` and `func2` as template argument, so I can write something like `wrapper<func1, func2> wrapped`?

---

EDIT:

after some experiment, I realized that I can declare the wrapper as:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2, T1(*f1)(), T2(*f2)(T1)>
```

then I can create the wrapper by:

```cpp
wrapper<int, double, f1, f2> wrapped；
```

So `f1` and `f2` are in template argument, but I still need to provide the type.

---

MORE EDIT:

To clarify, the reason I think I need a class template rather than std::bind is that I need to store some variable inside the class for next call.

After more research, I found I can do this if using c++17:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<auto f1, auto f2>
struct wrapper {
    using Tval = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(f1)>;
    using Tret = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(f2), Tval>;
    wrapper(Tret init) : m_last(init) {}
    Tret operator() () {
        auto val = f1();
        auto res = m_last + f2(val);
        m_last = res;
        return res;
    }
    Tret m_last;
};

int f1() {return 1;}
double f2(int val) {return int(val) / 10.0;}

int main() {
    auto f_wrapped = wrapper<f1, f2>(10);
    std::cout<<f_wrapped()<<std::endl;  // 10.1
    std::cout<<f_wrapped()<<std::endl;  // 10.2
}
```

This is pretty close to what I want. Only remaining issue is that I can change the argument type of `f2` to something different from the return type of `f1`, e.g. `double` in the above example code and the compiler will just do a silent conversion.

Comment: That's not a deducible context, so you must specify the arguments. `wrapper` is a class template; the template arguments have to come from *somewhere*. You *could* make a `mkwrapper` function that would do it.  Personally I'd skip all this and just wire up a `std::bind` chain with an intermediate lambda for your "Here I want to do something", but I imagine it's more complex than you're letting on.

Comment: I can imagine some wizardry being done involving a custom type of a function that consumes a supervariant of all types(let's call it "var") as input(so that all arguments can be passed as a single object) and produces a supervariant of all types, effectively turning your code into "I can't believe it's not javascript/lisp" but I imagine that's beyond what you're interested in doing, but they could be composed roughly as easily as javascript functions would be, but you would lose static analysis.

Comment: This looks like computing a composition of f1 and f2 and then accumulating the results. Why not separate the tasks?

Comment: So the remaining issue is that you want to prohibit the implicit conversion from return type of `f1` to parameter type of `f2`?

Comment: @Nimrod Yes. Obviously I can turn on compiler option `-Wconversion` to warn me of this issue, but I am wonder if there is something to enforce it.

Comment: One way do disable the type conversion is to `template <typename T> double f2(T) = delete;`  Or if you're using  C++20, use concepts to restrict the argument. But I don't think there's a way to apply to all functions in a function wrapper.

Comment: I do think out a way. See https://godbolt.org/z/osKf5358W But I think there's still a long to go since there're hundreds of cases which should work but not here.. For example `double f2(int&)` should work.